# How to merge text on image in windows phone app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am developing an app in which i need to write text on image and save it by coding in windows phone. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in Windows Phone 8. [Follow this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/05/07/step-by-step-tutorial-to-merge-text-on-image-customize-live-tiles-and-save-it-into-the-media-library-windows-phone-8-visual-studio-2012-using-c.aspx) but for higher versions you need to look for equivalent APIs.